# Can't install pycrypto keep getting errors

Tags: python, encryption, pip, pycharm, cryptography

I've tried pip installing and recently tried to install by going to file - > settings - > project interpreter and searching pycrypto and installing and i still can't get it to install. Here's the error I'm getting.

```
Collecting pycrypto
```

Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycrypto, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
Running setup.py install for pycrypto: started
Running setup.py install for pycrypto: finished with status 'error'

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated and has no effect anymore. pip 21.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\Bandi\PycharmProjects\filevault\random\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5o0scfjs\pycrypto_7048e726b6ba451795258a2a2a537fd9\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5o0scfjs\pycrypto_7048e726b6ba451795258a2a2a537fd9\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w8qs6kfk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bandi\PycharmProjects\filevault\random\include\site\python3.9\pycrypto'
cwd: C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5o0scfjs\pycrypto_7048e726b6ba451795258a2a2a537fd9
Complete output (185 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto
copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto
copying lib\Crypto_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\Hash_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Hash
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\Cipher_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Cipher
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
copying lib\Crypto\Util_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Util
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
copying lib\Crypto\Random_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
copying lib\Crypto\Random_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
copying lib\Crypto\Protocol_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Protocol
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\PublicKey
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
copying lib\Crypto\Signature_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\Crypto\Signature
Skipping optional fixer: buffer
Skipping optional fixer: idioms
Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
warning: PCTBuildPy: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

```
running build_ext
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Isrc/ -Isrc/inc-msvc/ -IC:\Users\Bandi\PycharmProjects\filevault\random\include -IC:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/winrand.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/winrand.obj
winrand.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(31): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(32): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(33): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(35): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(47): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(51): error C2059: syntax error: ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(53): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(55): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(61): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(68): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(74): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(81): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(87): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(94): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(100): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Bandi\PycharmProjects\filevault\random\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5o0scfjs\pycrypto_7048e726b6ba451795258a2a2a537fd9\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5o0scfjs\pycrypto_7048e726b6ba451795258a2a2a537fd9\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bandi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w8qs6kfk\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bandi\PycharmProjects\filevault\random\include\site\python3.9\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 6):

`pycrypto` is an old library and don't know if it is being maintained. Use pycryptodome instead:

`pip install pycryptodome`

This library is compatible with the same code as `pycrypto`.